# How do you make use of VT-d features other than PCI passthrough?

Tags: virtualization, intel-vt-x

I did some research and from what I can tell the main feature that *VT-d* provides is *PCI passthrough*.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Graphics_Virtualization_Technology_(Intel_GVT-d,_GVT-g_and_GVT-s)
>
> An input/output memory management unit (IOMMU) allows guest virtual
>   machines to directly use peripheral devices, such as Ethernet,
>   accelerated graphics cards, and hard-drive controllers, through DMA
>   and interrupt remapping. **This is sometimes called PCI passthrough.**

The next paragraph from the same article:

> An IOMMU also allows operating systems to eliminate bounce buffers
>   needed to allow themselves to communicate with peripheral devices
>   whose memory address spaces are smaller than the operating system's
>   memory address space, by using memory address translation. At the same
>   time, an IOMMU also allows operating systems and hypervisors to
>   prevent buggy or malicious hardware from compromising memory security.

I'm don't fully understand the implications of the above paragraph.

**Questions**

Assuming I'm using a hypervisor that can make use of all VT-d features:

1. If I'm not making use of *PCI passthrough*, will enabling *VT-d* improve guest performance?
2. Will I gain any security benefits by simply enabling VT-d without any additional configuration of the host OS/hypervisor/VMs?
3. Is there any reason not to enable VT-d if I'm not making any use of its features? For example does enabling VT-d have the potential to slow down the host?

Any other information would also be appreciated.